# why my program isn't showing correct result?

Tags: c

I wrote the following code for 
**this**

Given an integer number, Write a C program that displays the number as follows:

- First line : all digits
- Second line : all digits except first digit
- Third line: all except first two digits
- last line : the last digit

For eg.,
the number 5678 will be displayed as:

```
5 6 7 8
6 7 8
7 8
8
```

**=>**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>
main()
{
    long int x,y,n,z,i=1;
    printf("enter no. of digits=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("x=");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while(i<=n)
    {
       y=x/pow(10,i);
       z=y*pow(10,i);
       printf("%d\n",(x-z));
       i++;
    }
}
```

The code works(if we ignore the formatting) but does some rounding of and stuff fr some output values ...don't know why?? 
There are [solutions](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110809051841AAaIJop) using array and all...but whts wrong with this one??

Comment: *The code works but does some rounding of and stuff fr some output values.* What does that mean **in English** ?

Comment: What is an example of a situation where it doesn't work?

Comment: Give input, expected output, actual output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by "some values" with problems, you're referring to values that have zeroes in them, such as input like `50345`, which will print:

```
50345
345
345
45
5
```

rather than:

```
50345
0345
345
45
5
```

The problem is that the integer representation of numerical values does not acknowledge leading zeroes as being a unique integer value.

If you must print the values, including leading zeroes, you're going to have to treat your number like a token or string, meaning that a value that has leading zeroes is a unique string value from the version without leading zeroes.  This is why the array-versions, which treat the numeral value like a string, work, and your current version does not when presented with this type of input case.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding off you are seeing could be because of the use of `int` as data type for all the variables. So something like `(5/10)` would be rounded to 0 and not 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{
int num, count=0, x,no;
printf("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
no=num;


printf("The number you entered is:\n %d\n",num);
while(num){
    num=num/10;
    count++;
}

for(;count>1;count--){
x=pow(10,count-1);
printf("%d\n",no%x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int number,i=0;
    int digits[8];
    scanf("%d"&number);
while(number!=0)
{
digits[i]=numder%10;
number=number/10;
i++
}
for(i=i-1;i>=0;i--){
for(j=i;j>=0;j--){
printf("%d ",digits[j]);
}
printf("\n"):
}
}
```